# jQuery .load() Messing with Unicode Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unicode

I have set up a simple AJAX page loading script on my site and so far everything is working except for the Unicode Characters in the `<title>` get screwed up when loading the new content.

My jQuery setup looks like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var main = $("main");

    menuLinks.click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href"),
            ajaxLoad = function (html) {
                document.title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1].trim();
                main.fadeIn('slow');
            };

        history.pushState(null, null, href);
        main.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            main.load(href + ' main>*', ajaxLoad);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

My `<title>` have dashes in them and they end up as `&#8211;` when the page titles are loaded. I'm under the impression that this has to do something with jQuery and HTML using different encoding but am not sure how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var main = $("main");

    menuLinks.click(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr("href"),
            ajaxLoad = function (html) {
                document.title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1].text().trim();
                main.fadeIn('slow');
            };

        history.pushState(null, null, href);
        main.fadeOut('slow', function () {
            main.load(href + ' main>*', ajaxLoad);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: When I add `.text()` it doesn't pull the titles at all. Is this code working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `document.title = $(html).filter('title').text();` instead of `document.title = html.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1].trim();` and it seemed to do the trick in solving the unicode character issue.